# Code for macro to input data from excel to a website and copy the output back into the excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a coder. Hence i seek help of all the amazing people out here to provide a code .
I want to automate the below steps using macro :
Step 1 : I have a list of street address, zip and city in an excel file. Copy and paste the list in the website : https://smartystreets.com.
Step 2: Click on the process list button
Step 3: Copy the output from the website
Step 4: Paste the output in the excel file
It would be great if someone could help me out with this, as my manager requires it by tomorrow.
Thanks in advance,
Kavya

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read and follow this which will help you get answers: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). And by the way, smartystreets has an interface to do what you want, no need to copy/copy back: [The API to Address It All](https://smartystreets.com/features). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [iMacro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en).  It's web browser automation extension available on all major browsers (I recommend Google Chrome).  As you mentioned you have very little experience coding, you will find recording iMacros to be your best bet.

You may also want to consider editing your post, as the wording will inevitably cause it to get downvoted into oblivion.